# Zabbix hold files on windows OS

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, zabbix

The essence of the problem: Zabbix does not allow deleting files in Windows.
It is especially critical when files need to be deleted every day.

I guess that's the issue with this item:

```
vfs.dir.size[D:\oracle\fast_recovery_area\db ]
```

Error message:

[image: Image with error]

Check configuration:

[image: zabbix item config]

Comment: Zabbix by its own does not touch any files. Please provide your relevant check scripts.

Comment: Look at the error screen, it shows that the Zabbix agent is "holding" the file.

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize that this is the configured check. Since this is an internal check I'd file a bug report with Zabbix. Make sure the check isn't just currently running before you do, this would be normal while a check is running.

Comment: These files have been held for the third day.
The check is performed once a minute.
Added a screen with an item in Zabbix.

Answer (score 0):

You have configured an update interval of 1m. If the check takes longer than that (depends on the size of the directory) chances are that the directory is always locked.
Increase the time interval. Do you really need it with a granularity of 1 minute? Maybe 15 minutes or even an hour is enough.

Comment: You can just click on the `Test` button and check how long the check takes.

Comment: Hello. The duration of the check is less than a second.
Zabbix locks different files inside subfolders each time. As a result, I have a tree of folders, each with 1-2 files out of hundreds.

Comment: In that case, as I already suggested, I'd report it as a bug.